# IE 10 inconsistent display

Tags: internet-explorer-10

I am experiencing a display problem in IE 9 and 10.  No such problem in FF, Chrome.

On SOME of my pages, and then on only 25-30% of the page refreshes, the contents are pushed to the bottom of an infinitely long page, leaving a blank space visibly between the bottom of the navigation and the top of the content.  The frequency is higher when the history/cache is cleared.

The code is essentially like this:

```
<div class="column">
<div class="inner-column"> . . .</div>
<div class="xyz">. . . </div>
<div class="nmk"> . . . </div>
</div>
```

The "column" div displays infinitely long and the "inner-column" div and everything below it visually sit at the bottom of "column."

The behavior toggles in response to *anything* that re-writes the screen i.e. zooming in/out, or inspecting the page and turning on/off css properties, regardless of the property.

This code structure is the same for all pages, the ones that display this problem and the ones that don't.

I've tried to figure out what the "good" pages have vs. the "bad" pages and can't identify the magic combination.  The most difficult part is that the "bad" pages display incorrectly only part of the time.
This is a Drupal 7 site, but I don't think the issue is Drupal related, specifically.

Has anyone else seen this kind of behavior?

Comment: Can you recreate this in a fiddle so we can see an example of your CSS and any JS you have? It's difficult to tell anything without knowing the widths, heights, position, float, etc. of these elements, as well as the context.

Comment: Yes, I want to do this.  But have never created a fiddle before.  For a Drupal page, do I just copy/paste the viewed source - more or less?

Comment: @IvanDurst, I have created this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mastoll/LPjjS/.  While it is a cut/paste directly from view-source, I haven't been able to make it behave as described above, but I'm also having difficulties working with JSFiddle in IE10 as I can't scroll the panel that contains the resource list, so I can't tweak the resources sufficiently.

Answer (score 0):

With help, I've been able to better-characterize the problem and found that it derives from a left-floated column within which the top element has a top margin of X%.  When either of those properties is changed (i.e. the parent is not floated or the first-child has margin-top:Ypx), the errant behavior does not occur.

This column is floated by the template in anticipation of a multi-column display.  Since there is no point at which I need another column to wrap around this one, I have removed the float and all is well.

I don't know why this magic combination of floating-parent and top-margin-in-percentage-child causes the top margin to expand to infinity, only in IE10.  Anyone have knowledge of how these values are implemented that would shed some light on this?